# How can I reuse a text file in a C program without having a file pointer?

Tags: c

My program has uses a text file to input data, but can't use a file pointer in the program itself. I'm supposed to use the < file.txt in the Linux terminal. I can't do it any other way because it's a college assignment, so please don't waste my time with rewind or other functions that require a pointer. I just need to be able to basically restart the text file that I already have open.

Comment: You do have a `FILE*` for your standard input, [the `stdin` macro](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c#Macros). It might not do what you want if it needs to work even if standard input is from the terminal instead of a regular file. If that's the case, you pretty much just have to store what you read from stdin, or find a way to make your program one-pass.

Comment: Thanks! It works. Sometimes I feel like I have no idea what's going on with this stuff... just going with the flow and using google a ton.

Comment: Then I made it a full answer, with more detail.

Comment: Read from file provided as first argument (or from `stdin` by default), e.g. `FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;` Then `./my_prog < file` works just fine. (or `./my_prog file` also works) -- your choice.

Comment: @DanielH: Strictly he may not even use `stdin`, as he "*can't use a file pointer*", which `stdin` is.

Comment: @alk I assume that meant he had to use standard input instead of creating a file pointer by `fopen`. Without an actual quote from the assignment or asking the professor, it's hard to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

The C library provides a `FILE` pointer for standard input, [`stdin` from `<stdio.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io#Macros). However, it might not support all the functions you want, since it can be connected to another command (if you pipe your input from somewhere else) or the terminal (if you don't use input redirection). If you need to be able to support these, *which you probably do*, you won't be able to successfully call `fseek` or any of the related functions.

If that's the case, then this is fundamentally impossible. The computer doesn't store all the data which was sent to your program, so there is no way to go back and get it because there's nowhere to get it from. Instead, you either need to store the input yourself, or rework your algorithm to only need a single pass over the input data.